# When I add the attribute Auto increment, it wants me to declare the column in my insert statement?

Tags: python, sqlite, primary-key, auto-increment

When creating my table I have declared the a column as the primary Key with auto_increment.

But when I insert a row into my column, it wants me to either add in the primary key but declare it first, or when I don't put the primary key in, it says I haven't given it enough arguments.

Nearly every site I have been to tells me that i don't have to add the primary key into my insert statement as it will auto increment itself, but it doesn't seem to do that.

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS class(

         student_ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
         first TEXT,
         last TEXT,
         mark INTEGER,
         target_grade TEXT,
         percentage INTEGER 


)""")
```

Later on...

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO class VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",
          (first,last,mark,target_grade,percentage,))
```

> sqlite3.OperationalError: table class has 6 columns but 5 values were supplied

or

> NameError: name 'ID' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must include in the `INSERT` statement the names of the columns that will receive the values (don't include the primary key column of course):

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO class (first, last, mark, target_grade, percentage) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",(first,last,mark,target_grade,percentage,))
```

Comment: Also: It's [AUTOINCREMENT](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) and not AUTO_INCREMENT. If you declare the PK as just PRIMARY KEY it will also create a unique id. And the last comma after `percentage` is not necessary.

Comment: I get no error this time, however my primary key column comes out as 'none' instead of numbers...any suggestions?

Comment: @NahilaChowdhury see my comment

Comment: Remove AUTO_INCREMENT from the create statement.

Comment: Just: `student_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is enough and the column will be autoincrement.

Comment: and still get 'none'

Comment: The code should work if you recreate the table. Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mYEM4hWTTvm7ZdbU7ECHj7/0